# iOS Login again into GameCenter

Tags: ios, game-center

How can I display the GameCenter Login view again, if a user has canceled during first login attempt.

I am using the following code from raywenderlich tutorial,

```
-(void) authenticateLocalPlayer {

    __weak GKLocalPlayer* localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {

        [self setLastError:error];

        if (localPlayer.authenticated) {
            _gameCenterFeaturesEnabled = YES;
            currentPlayer = localPlayer;

            //NSLog(@"Authenticated User");
                [self.delegate2 enableButtonOnAuthentication];

        } else if(viewController) {
            [self presentViewController:viewController];
        } else {
            _gameCenterFeaturesEnabled = NO;
        }
    };
}
```

The above method is called from `viewDidLoad`,

```
[[GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper] authenticateLocalPlayer];
[[GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper] setDelegate2:self];
```

If a user cancels the login, I am displaying a message, "to play you must login".

And if tries to call the above method again on a button click the `block` code does not seems to execute.

Can you point out to what am I doing wrong here?